# SQL Server DBA moving to Greenplum / Postgres on Linux ( Centos ) looking for friendly MS Sql Agent like scheduler instead of CRON

Tags: cron, postgresql

To be honest, I and others are spoiled by Microsoft's SQL Agent.  We'd really like to keep properties of SQL Agent : the features, the usable GUI.

I searched serverfault for an evaluation of different CRON GUIs / Scheduling agents, but really didn't find quite what I was looking for.  So, I'd like your input.

- What's worked well for you, been usable.
- I'd especially like to hear from someone who has approached it from my point of view.
- What is your experience with the below 3 options?

Seems like our options are so far are:

- PgAgent - seems just the ticket.  Unfortunately, it doesn't work well with Greenplum.  Also, it looks like it might be somewhat abandoned - the last release date was some time ago.  But it might just be that it's so well done, it hasn't needed new releases.
- Job Scheduler, http://jobscheduler.sourceforge.net/, which on first glance, seems to fit pretty well.  But I'm a bit concerned that it might have complications in order to generate consulting revenue.  It also just doesn't 'feel' like SQL Agent, reading the docs, many of the concepts feel foreign.  On the plus side, it certainly looks to be kept up.
- Cron

  - learning more advanced techniques like ( [Cron jobs in cascade array](https://serverfault.com/questions/118133/cron-jobs-in-cascade-array), [job control and ssh](https://serverfault.com/questions/25301/job-control-and-ssh), [Can I run a cron job more frequently than every minute?](https://serverfault.com/questions/49082/can-i-run-a-cron-job-more-frequently-than-every-minute), [Where is this cron job running from?](https://serverfault.com/questions/103482/where-is-this-cron-job-running-from), [Cron job unified logging](https://serverfault.com/questions/116598/cron-job-unified-logging) )
  - But honestly, the techniques seem obscure, due to my background, and I'm seriously concerned that if we go down this road, we'll make serious mistakes and do some really hard learning

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you have the option of running the central scheduler on a Windows box, have a look at [**JAMS**](http://www.jamsscheduler.com/) by MVP Software.  It has agents for just about anything you could ask for.  We evaluated it and it is quite powerful.  The scheduler is very much Windows-centric, though, so I'm not sure it'll completely fit in your environment and I admittedly don't know how well it integrates into Greenplum...

Comment: Yeah, they at least have a great website / demos.  I'll have to look into their pricing.

Comment: JAMS is more product than I'm looking for.  If I had the budget, I could justify looking deeper into it.